# Lightning component <a> tag URL with expressions

Tags: lightning-aura-components, lightning

I am bulding the URL with attribute values., so I am getting this error. Is there a way we can have multiple attributes in URL?

```
<a href="{! 'http://example.sample.net/forms/view/261086?tfa_98=' + v.timesheetRecord.Internship__r.Student_Contact__r.Id + '&tfa_99='+v.timesheetRecord.Id }"   target="_new" >
```

**Error:**

> Failed to save sendTimesheetEmial.cmp: 0Ad0t0000008k7m:58,170:
>   ParseError at [row,col]:[59,170] Message: The reference to entity
>   "tfa_99" must end with the ';' delimiter.: Source

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need to escape the `&` using an XML character entity:

```
'&amp;tfa_99='
```

Comment: That worked. I will keep track of this for future.

Answer (score 0):

@Ajay, I am not familair with your specific use case, however, you are not the first person asking `<a>` tag related questions related to lightning components.

Please check the [Lightning Components Developer Guide](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.lightning.meta/lightning/ref_supported_html_tags_a.htm) in regards to using Anchor tags:

> Don’t hard code or dynamically generate Salesforce URLs in the href
>   attribute of an  tag. Use events, such as force:navigateToSObject
>   or force:navigateToURL, instead.
>
> **Avoid the href Attribute**
>
> Using the href attribute of an  tag leads
>   to inconsistent behavior in different apps and shouldn’t be relied on.
>   For example, don’t use this markup to link to a record:
>
> `<a href="/XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX">Salesforce record ID (DON'T DO THIS)</a>`
>
> If you use # in the href attribute, a secondary issue occurs. The hash
>   mark (#) is a URL fragment identifier and is often used in Web
>   development for navigation within a page. Avoid # in the href
>   attribute of anchor tags in Lightning components as it can cause
>   unexpected navigation changes, especially in the Salesforce app.
>   That’s another reason not to use href.

Comment: That's good Salesforce-specific advice, but wouldn't be applicable to links outside of Salesforce.

Comment: indeed, just hoping the OP is aware of this, and if not, will be for future reference =)

Comment: I agree, I have to put this link in between the text. Unavoiadable.